# Constructing pattern of two characters (ex: "aabba","aba")

Tags: java, string, sequence

Suggest an efficient way to construct `String` with a pattern of two characters (ex: "aabba","aba") given the frequency of both the characters (ex: `x = 5, y = 4`). 
The catch is any character should not repeat more than twice.

Example test cases:

```
|  X  |  Y  | Output     |
| --- | --- | ---------- |
|  3  |  2  | aabab      |
|  2  |  1  | aab        |
|  4  |  6  | bbabbababa |
|  4  |  4  | abababab   |
```

I have written a greedy method as follows,

```
public static String getPatternStr(int x, int y){
    String result = "";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int secondIterationIndex = 0;

    int moreCharCount = (x > y)? x : y;
    int lessCharCount = (x < y)? x : y;


    String moreChar = (x > y)?"a":"b";
    String lessChar = (x < y)?"a":"b";

    if(x == y){
        moreCharCount = lessCharCount = x;
        moreChar = "a";
        lessChar = "b";
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= (x+y); i++){
        if(lessCharCount > 0){
            if(i%2 == 1){
                list.add(moreChar);
                moreCharCount--;
            }
            else{
                list.add(lessChar);
                lessCharCount--;
            }
        }else{
            list.add(secondIterationIndex,moreChar);
            secondIterationIndex += 3;
            if(secondIterationIndex > list.size()){
                secondIterationIndex = list.size()-1; 
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(list);
    }
    for(String e: list){
        result += e;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This method seems cumbersome and not elegant. Please suggest any better and efficient method?

Edit: I strongly believe there a way using these (x and y) numbers, we can calculate number of double-a's, double-b's, single-a's and single-b's, even before looping starts. Got only a partially working logic.

```
public static String patternStr(int x, int y){
    String result = "";

    int large = (x > y)? x : y;
    int small = (x < y)? x : y;


    int pairsOfLarge = large/2;
    int largeParts = pairsOfLarge + large%2;

    int minSmallParts = (largeParts>1)? (largeParts-1):1;
    int pairsOfSmall = small - minSmallParts;
    int smallParts = pairsOfSmall + (small - (pairsOfSmall*2));
    // System.out.println("minSmallParts="+minSmallParts+" pairsOfSmall="+pairsOfSmall+" smallParts="+smallParts);

    String odd = (large == x)?"a":"b";
    String even = (small == x)?"a":"b";

    int i = 1;
    while((largeParts + smallParts) > 0){
        if(i%2 > 0){
            if(pairsOfLarge > 0){
                result += odd + odd;
                pairsOfLarge--;
            }else{
                result += odd;
            }
            largeParts--;
        }else{
            if(pairsOfSmall > 0){
                result += even + even;
                pairsOfSmall--;
            }else{
                result += even;
            }
            smallParts--;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `aabbaabb` also work for X=4, Y=4?

Comment: That is also fine, only condition is "a" or "b" should not repeat more than 2 times consecutively.

Comment: Am I correct that there is no solution if the difference between X and Y is greater than 3?

Comment: Aren't you missing a check whether it is actually possible to solve the problem? 5 1 shouldnt work for example.

Comment: @Sweeper If x=7 and y=3 (7-3=4) the pattern "aabaabaaba" is fine.

Comment: @GhostCat The check is appreciated, but not mandatory.

Comment: Well, without that check, there is a chance that your code will throw exceptions at some point, or return invalid results. Or maybe not.

Comment: And just for the record: we dont review working code here. You might want to check whether https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place.

Answer (score 1):

This is more elegant to me (the working of the algorithm is similar tho):

```
static String getPatternStr(int x, int y){
    int lessCharCount = Math.min(x,y);
    int moreCharCount = Math.max(x,y);
    String moreChar = "a";
    String lessChar = "b";
    if(lessCharCount < (moreCharCount + 1) / 2 - 1)
      return "";
    if(lessCharCount == 1 && moreCharCount == 1)
      return moreChar + lessChar;
    LinkedList<String> result = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(moreChar.repeat(moreCharCount).split("")));
    for(int i = 2; lessCharCount > 0; i = (i + 3) % (++moreCharCount)){
      result.add(i,lessChar);
      lessCharCount--;
    }
    return result.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(""));
  }
```

There is no much efficiency gain, only that LinkedList is used rather than ArraysList, the former being better for insertion operation.

Comment: Thanks, looks cleaner. Also I edited the question to include one more approach I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

if you found repeat character for example : "bbabbababa".

```
String value = "bbabbababa";
    ArrayList<Character> charList = new ArrayList<>();

    value.chars()
        .forEach(e -> charList.add((char) e));

    System.out.println("b : " + Collections.frequency(charList, 'b'));
```

**output :** b : 6